# How to know which pin triggered the interrupt with i.MX6?

Tags: arm, interrupt, imx6, nxp-microcontroller

I'm working on interrupts with i.MX6 processor.

As @RodBorras said in [this thread](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/Interrupts-with-GPIO1-INT0-7/m-p/221515):

*"This is my understanding of how the MX6Q GPIO interrupts work:*

*a) GPIO1 (32 pins) through GPIO7 (32 pins) can be configured to generate interrupts when the pins are set to inputs*

*b) GPIO2 through GPIO7 do not have an "ARM interrupt" for each pin, but rather for the OR'ed results of 16 pins*

*==> e.g. GPIO2 will cause an "ARM IRQ 100" if there is a valid interrupt    on any pin within 0-15*

*==> e.g. GPIO2 will cause an "ARM IRQ 101" if there is a valid interrupt    on any pin within 16-31*

*==> So even though GPIO2 can monitor 32 pins for activity, the ARM Core will only see 1 of 2 IRQs happen (#100 or #101)*

*c) GPIO1 has the same functionality as described in b), but also some further granularity: its bottom 8 pins (0-7) will cause 8 specific "ARM interrupts"*

*==> GPIO1_0 will cause an "ARM IRQ 97", and so on for pins 1,2,3,4,5,6; GPIO1_7 will cause an "ARM IRQ 90"*

*==> for GPIO1_8 through GPIO1_31, these can only be seen through "ARM IRQ98" for pins 0-15, or "ARM IRQ99" for pins 16-31"*

So if we take the example of two interrupts of the same group (for example, two pins between 0 and 15 of GPIO2), how can we know which pin triggered the interrupt?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From NXP TechSupport answer: *"Interrupt source can be obtained reading GPIOx_ISR register described in sect.28.5.7 GPIO interrupt status register (GPIOx_ISR)"*

Here is the corresponding register description from [this document](https://www.nxp.com/webapp/Download?colCode=IMX6DQRM).

[image]